# absolute convergence and series. bounded sequences

Tags: real-analysis

If $\sum\limits z_n$  converges relatively and $\sum\limits z_lk_n $ also converges readily, then $k_n$ must be bounded. someone?

Comment: What if $c_n=0$ and $k_n$ arbitrary?

Answer (score 1):

This is false. $\sum 1/n^3$ and $\sum n/n^3$ both converge absolutely. But $n$ is obviously not bounded.

Comment: can it be proved without a counter example?

Comment: Prove that it is false? A counterexample *is* a proof that it is false.